# How to Databind in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is **Model**

```
class DataModel
{
    string _inputvalue;                    
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _inputvalue; }
        set { _inputvalue= value; }
    }           
}
```

This is ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DataModel _data;

    public MyViewModel ()
    {
        _data = new DataModel { FirstName= "DefaultName" };
    }

    public DataModel Data
    {
        get{return _data;}
        set{_data = value;}
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _data.FirstName; }

        set {_data.FirstName= "NewName";
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName"):
            }
    }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

This is **View**

```
  <TextBox  Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                   Margin="8,59,76,122" />
```

My questions are:

1) Since I have just started MVVM i want to know if  this the right way of doing it??

2) I want my `FirstName`  to come from Dataset. sample code would be like

```
  string _getname=MyDS.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

Where can I place this code ??

Thank you All

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are on the right track.
2. It belongs in or near the model. Since you do not want to create models in your view model constructor, you need to inject some sort of repository service into the view model that gives you access to creating and retrieving models. This repository or the model itself will then have access to the tables, data sets etc.

Here is a crude example for the view model:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private IModelRepository _repository;

  public MyViewModel(IModelRepository repository)
  {
    _repository = repository;
    Models = repository.GetAllModels();
  }

  public IEnumerable<DataModel> Models { get; set; }
}

public interface IModelRepository
{
  IEnumerable<DataModel> GetAllModels();
}

public class MyRepository : IModelRepository
{
  public IEnumerable<DataModel> GetAllModels()
  {
    // obviously nowhere near final code!!!
    return new List<DataModel> { 
                      new DataModel { 
                             FirstName = MyDS.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString() 
                      } 
               };
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your Quick response I am not clear with the second point (Maybe it is the jargon )..